# Find the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$ with pdf $f(x)=2x/\theta^2$

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, inference

Let $(X_1,\dots, X_n)$ be a random sample from $X$ with pdf $f(x)=2x/\theta^2$ for $0\le x\le \theta$ where $\theta>0$. Find the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$.

---

The likelihood function is that
$$
L(\theta)=\frac{2^n}{\theta^{2n}}\prod_{i}x_i
$$

I know that we need to find the $\theta$ that maximized the $L(\theta)$. But I did not know how to get $\theta=X_{(n)}$... I try to get the derivative of this one but $\theta=0$.

Comment: $$L(\theta)=\begin{cases}\frac{2^n}{\theta^{2n}}\prod_{i}x_i &\quad \text{if $\theta \geq x_i$ for all $x_i$}\\ 0 &\quad \text{if $\theta < x_i$ for at least one $x_i$ } \end{cases}$$ The problem here is that the maximum is in a point where the derivative is non-zero. The maximum occurs because of a discontinuity, not because the derivative is zero.

Comment: The [German Tank problem](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=German+tank) is the typical example of these kind of problems. If you search for [the term $\mathbb{I}$](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22%5Cmathbb%7BI%7D%22+likelihood), the indicator function that occurs in the answer of user1865345, then you come across several variants of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

Here $$L(\theta)=\frac{2^n}{\theta^{2n}}\left(\prod_{i}x_i \right)\mathbb I_{(0,\theta]}\left(x_{(n)}\right).$$

Only two factors above depend on $\theta.$ See how increasing (decreasing) $\theta$ in the first factor affects $L.$ Then determine $\hat{\theta}_{\textrm{MLE}}$ based on the last factor.